# label doesn't work inside gather*

Tags: equations, labels

I am successfully using gather* to centre align my groups of equations. However, if I do:

```
\begin{gather*}
\rho=a*b \\
\alpha=2*\rho. 
              \label{eqn_one}
\end{gather*}
```

It shows two equations centre aligned (which is what I want), **but it doesn't have equation label**. I want only 1 label for these 2 equations.

Comment: Of course not.. `gather*` has'n number so you can not refer it. I you like to do this, than use just `gather`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: `\label` doesn't print any numbers, it just sets a marker so you can refer to the whatever is the active number. `gather*` (and all other starred math environments) are unnumbered. So one number should apply to both, i.e. the number is for the group of equations? If so, see Zarko's answer. Or should just the second equation be numbered?

Answer (score 6):

Try

```
\begin{equation}
    \begin{gathered}
\rho=a*b \\
\alpha=2*\rho.
              \label{eqn_one}
    \end{gathered}
\end{equation}
```

`equation` provides one number for content, which is in `gathered` environment. Number is vertically centered. It centers two equations. For use of `gathered`, you need load package `amsmath` in preamble.

Comment: `gathered` is defined in `amsmath`.

Comment: Indeed! In the seem time I try to help to another question where I use `multline` environment and I check for it variant `multlined` ... and make this confusion. I apologies for this for. Thank you very much for correction!

Answer (score 4):

The command to remove the equation number is `\notag`.
Here a MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{gather}
\rho=a*b \notag\\
\alpha=2*\rho.
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

[image]